# How to show next div on click of parent div jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to put some effect on my page.On Click of main div i want to show hide the inner div.But it is not working for me

**HTML**

```
 <div class="cmn"><div><span></span></div>Here
        <div class="toShow" style="display: none;">
                <div class="toshowinnr clr">
                    <a class="sclnk" href="#"></a>
                    <a class="sclnk" href="#"></a>
                    <a class="sclnk" href="#"></a>
                    <a class="sclnk" href="#"></a>
                    <a class="sclnk" href="#"></a>
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
<div class="cmn"><div><span></span></div>Here
        <div class="toShow" style="display: none;">
                <div class="toshowinnr clr">
                    <a class="sclnk" href="#"></a>
                    <a class="sclnk" href="#"></a>
                    <a class="sclnk" href="#"></a>
                    <a class="sclnk" href="#"></a>
                    <a class="sclnk" href="#"></a>
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
<div class="cmn"><div><span></span></div>Here
        <div class="toShow" style="display: none;">
                <div class="toshowinnr clr">
                    <a class="sclnk" href="#"></a>
                    <a class="sclnk" href="#"></a>
                    <a class="sclnk" href="#"></a>
                    <a class="sclnk" href="#"></a>
                    <a class="sclnk" href="#"></a>
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
```

Onclick of `cmn` i want to show/hide `toShow div` .I have done this but this is not working for me.

```
jQuery('div.cmn').click(function(){
        jQuery(this).closest('div.toShow').stop().slideDown();
    }).mouseleave(function(){
        jQuery(this).closest('div.toShow').stop().slideUp();
    });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

YOu need to use .find() as you are looking for a descendant

```js
jQuery('div.cmn').click(function() {
  jQuery(this).find('div.toShow').stop().slideDown();
}).mouseleave(function() {
  jQuery(this).find('div.toShow').stop().slideUp();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cmn"><div><span></span></div>Here
  <div class="toShow" style="display: none;">
    <div class="toshowinnr clr">
      <a class="sclnk" href="#">1</a>
      <a class="sclnk" href="#">2</a>
      <a class="sclnk" href="#">3</a>
      <a class="sclnk" href="#">4</a>
      <a class="sclnk" href="#">5</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="cmn"><div><span></span></div>Here
  <div class="toShow" style="display: none;">
    <div class="toshowinnr clr">
      <a class="sclnk" href="#">1</a>
      <a class="sclnk" href="#">2</a>
      <a class="sclnk" href="#">3</a>
      <a class="sclnk" href="#">4</a>
      <a class="sclnk" href="#">5</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="cmn"><div><span></span></div>Here
  <div class="toShow" style="display: none;">
    <div class="toshowinnr clr">
      <a class="sclnk" href="#">1</a>
      <a class="sclnk" href="#">2</a>
      <a class="sclnk" href="#">3</a>
      <a class="sclnk" href="#">4</a>
      <a class="sclnk" href="#">5</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i have multiple toShow div and  cmn div i want to show closest div of cmn on which i have clicked

Comment: can we do this without using css simply in jquery

Comment: @Gaurav those css is used to put some random content to the anchor element.. dont have any functional meaning

Comment: @SidM how is it different from the above answer

Comment: @ArunPJohny: I'm using children() instead of find().. find will go down to complete hierarchy where as children goes only one level down.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<div class="cmn"><div><span></span></div>Here
<div class="toShow" style="display: none;">
        <div class="toshowinnr clr">
            <a class="sclnk" href="#">1</a>
            <a class="sclnk" href="#">2</a>
            <a class="sclnk" href="#">3</a>
            <a class="sclnk" href="#">4</a>
            <a class="sclnk" href="#">5</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="cmn"><div><span></span></div>Here
<div class="toShow" style="display: none;">
        <div class="toshowinnr clr">
            <a class="sclnk" href="#">6</a>
            <a class="sclnk" href="#">7</a>
            <a class="sclnk" href="#">8</a>
            <a class="sclnk" href="#">9</a>
            <a class="sclnk" href="#">10</a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

jQuery

This will always get you the first `div.toShow`

```
jQuery('div.cmn').click(function() {
  jQuery(this).children('div.toShow').first().stop().slideDown();
}).mouseleave(function() {
  jQuery(this).children('div.toShow').first().stop().slideUp();
});
```

**Fiddle:** [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sid_m/wgv78h0m/)

Answer (score 0):

i think this code will work for you.

```
  jQuery('div.cmn').click(function(event,ui){
        jQuery(ui).find('div.toShow').stop().slideDown();
    }).mouseleave(function(event,ui){
        jQuery(this).find('div.toShow').stop().slideUp();
    });
```

Comment: i have multiple toShow div and cmn div i want to show closest div of cmn on which i have clicked

Answer (score 0):

You need to set display:block css property to inner div. Have a look:

```
$(".cmn").on("click",function(){
  $(this).find(".toShow").toggleClass("hideshow");
});
```

css code

```
.hideshow
{
  display:block;
}
```

.toggleClass will check if "hideshow" class exist on div.toShow, if not then it will add class "hideshow" else it will remove ".hideshow" class which will perform hide/show on click of parent div.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".here_button").click(function() {
     
     $($(this).parents(".cmn").find(".toShow")[0]).css("display","block");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cmn">
  <div><span></span>
  </div><span class="here_button">Here</span>
  <div class="toShow" style="display: none;">
    <div class="toshowinnr clr">
      <a class="sclnk" href="#">Some Text</a>
      <a class="sclnk" href="#">Some Text</a>
      <a class="sclnk" href="#">Some Text</a>
      <a class="sclnk" href="#">Some Text</a>
      <a class="sclnk" href="#">Some Text</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="cmn">
  <div><span></span>
  </div><span class="here_button">Here</span>
  <div class="toShow" style="display: none;">
    <div class="toshowinnr clr">
      <a class="sclnk" href="#">Some Text</a>
      <a class="sclnk" href="#">Some Text</a>
      <a class="sclnk" href="#">Some Text</a>
      <a class="sclnk" href="#">Some Text</a>
      <a class="sclnk" href="#">Some Text</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="cmn">
  <div><span></span>
  </div><span class="here_button">Here</span>
  <div class="toShow" style="display: none;">
    <div class="toshowinnr clr">
      <a class="sclnk" href="#">Some Text</a>
      <a class="sclnk" href="#">Some Text</a>
      <a class="sclnk" href="#">Some Text</a>
      <a class="sclnk" href="#">Some Text</a>
      <a class="sclnk" href="#">Some Text</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```